# problems for hyperbolic geometry

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

I know some good books in elementary hyperbolic geometry but they have not 'good'
exercises.by good exercises I mean nontrivial beautiful problems.we have many resources in of this problems in Euclidean geometry do you know any resource for hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: by elementary I mean an undergraduate course

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the lack of answers, I guess that no such resource exists...

If you want something to force you to think about hyperbolic geometry, and gain informal intuitions about it, my [HyperRogue](http://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper/) could be appropriate. The closest to traditional geometric problems (though still rather far) is probably the land of Camelot, where your task is to find the center of a large hyperbolic circle.

Some problems I had to solve while writing HyperRogue:

- From what point do we have to look at the hyperboloid model of a hyperbolic plane, to see it in the Poincaré disk model? In the Klein model?
- A hyperbolic plane $A$ is isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{H}^3$ as an equidistant surface of radius $r$. We are looking at it from a point in distance $d$ above the base plane of $A$. For what values od $r$ and $d$ does $A$ look as in the Poincaré disk model? In the Klein model?
- Consider the truncated order-7 triangular tiling. Compute the number of tiles in distance of $d$ steps from a given heptagon or hexagon. (hard)
- Consider the truncated order-7 triangular tiling. We can create a shape by combining $n$ tiles together. Suppose that we can tile the hyperbolic plane with our shape. Show that $n$ is divisible by 10. (easy)
- What are the important lengths (edge, distance from hexagon vertex to center, distance from heptagon vertex to center, etc.) in the truncated order-7 triangular tiling? (I have not actually solved this problem -- HyperRogue finds these with binary search, but I think it can be done)